# How to make pagination with description of specific contents in each page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have totally 4 rows and each row is distributed into 3 columns as like below,

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here i need to do pagination, in which at first page two rows should be displayed and in next page two rows need to be displayed..
Here i used bootstrap pagination,

```
 <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="" rel="prev">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" rel="next">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
```

But its just for design i think.. How to make functionality to get contents by clicking the corresponding page number .. I don't have any idea related with it any good help would be helpful for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what should be done if the pages get more than 2?

***ANSWER UPDATED***

According to the comment the new code handles a variable number of pages. It's enough to define the page size as an attribute of the pagination element.

In the following the code with all the self explanatory comments:

```js
$(function () {
    //
    //  get num of rows and compute num of pages
    //
    var nRows = $('.container .row').length;
    var nPages = Math.ceil(nRows / $('.pagination').data('page-size'));
    //
    // save num pages as a data attribute of pagination element
    //
    $('.pagination').data('num-pages', nPages);
    //
    // Create the buttons on the fly
    //
    for(var i=1; i<nPages; i++) {
        $('<li/>').append($('<a/>', {href: "#", text: i + 1})).insertBefore('.pagination li:has([rel]):last');
    }
    //
    // handle pagination
    //
    $('.pagination li').on('click', function (e) {
        //
        // prevent default action
        //
        e.preventDefault();

        //
        // The clicked element is the next one......
        //
        var eleClicked = $(this);
        var nextEle = eleClicked;

        //
        // ....if the clicked element is Next or Prev buttons
        //
        var nextPrevAnchorEle = eleClicked.find('a[rel]');
        if (nextPrevAnchorEle.length == 1) {
            //
            // compute the next element
            //
            if (nextPrevAnchorEle.text().trim() == 'Next') {
                nextEle = $('.pagination li.active').next('li:not(:has([rel]))');
                if (nextEle.length == 0) {
                    nextEle = $('.pagination li:not(:has([rel])):first');
                }
            } else {
                nextEle = $('.pagination li.active').prev('li:not(:has([rel]))');
                if (nextEle.length == 0) {
                    nextEle = $('.pagination li:not(:has([rel])):last');
                }
            }
        }
        //
        // toggle active page
        //
        $('.pagination li.active').removeClass('active');
        nextEle.addClass('active');

        //
        // get the number of active page
        //
        var currentPageNumber = +nextEle.find('a').text().trim() - 1;

        //
        // get the page size
        //
        var pageSize = +$('.pagination').data('page-size');
        //
        // toggle visibility
        //
        $('.container .row:visible').toggle(false);
        $('.container .row').slice(currentPageNumber * pageSize, (currentPageNumber + 1) * pageSize).toggle(true);
    });
    //
    // show the active page
    //
    $('.pagination li.active a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Init your HTML with a pagination containing only Prev, Next and first page and set active to the first page -->
<ul class="pagination" data-page-size="2">
    <li><a href="" rel="prev">Prev</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" rel="next">Next</a></li>
</ul>
<!--  Add as many rows as needed  in the container -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">1
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">1
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">1
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">2
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">2
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">2
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">3
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">3
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">3
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">4
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">4
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">4
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">5
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">5
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">5
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">6
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">6
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">6
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">7
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">7
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">7
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">8
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">8
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">8
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">9
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">9
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">9
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> How to make functionality to get contents by clicking the corresponding page number

I assume you want to implement the pagination functionality: move next, move previous, select page 1, select page 2 and so display the correct page (i.e.: for page 1 the first two rows, for the second page the last two rows).

If this is the case, you may achieve your goal:

- hide the first two rows because the default active is on the second page
- add a click event handler for each page navigation button: in this handler take the appropriate actions: toggle visibility and change active page.

```js
//
// hide the first 2 rows
//
$('.container .row:lt(2)').hide();

$('.pagination li').on('click', function(e) {
    //
    // prevent default action
    //
    e.preventDefault();
    //
    // toggle active page
    //
    var lis = $(this).closest('.pagination').find('a:not([rel])')
                   .closest('li').toggleClass('active');
    //
    // get the number of active page
    //
    var txt = lis.filter('.active').find('a').text().trim();
    //
    // toggle visibility
    //
    $('.container .row:lt(2)').toggle(txt == '1');
    $('.container .row:gt(1)').toggle(txt == '2');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="" rel="prev">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" rel="next">Next</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">1
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">1
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">1
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">2
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">2
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">2
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">3
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">3
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">3
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">4
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">4
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">4
            <img src="img/portfolio/sd.png" alt="portfolio" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works good.. But if i give active to the first page, then in what manner should i change the jquery? Now i changed like this $('.portfolio-container .row:gt(1)').hide(); but when we click the 2nd page, a additional row was added at above but it its display is none but taking the row space..(i.e), in 2nd page 3 rows were displaying..

Comment: And what should be done if the pages gets more than 2?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answers and helpful reply in quick manner..